# Renew in-house distribution certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning, in-house-distribution, airwatch

For apple enterprise account, we are using In-house distribution certificate and around 100 apps are tied to it. Some of the apps also have Push notifications enabled with it. We are using Airwatch as MDM agent for app deployment. This distribution certificate is expiring on 1st November.

#### Solution I am aware of :-

1. Create a new In-house distribution certificate ahead of time.
2. Regenerate provisioning profile of all 100 apps with newly created distribution certificate.
3. Re-build all of the apps with new certificate and provisioning profile.
4. Deploy new apps version through Airwatch.

#### Question:-

Just wanted to know how to use newly created certificate , regenerated provisioning profiles without building all of 100 apps again.

Comment: Even if you re-signed the existing build with the new certificate you still need to update all of the installed apps on your devices; Rebuilding the apps and using the standard signing process is probably simpler.  You can now "sell" B2B apps to yourself, so that is something you might want to look into;  The downside is your custom app still goes through App Store review, the upside is the provisioning profile and distribution certificates never expire; The apps are just like regular AppStore signed apps.

Answer (score 0):

Apple allows you to generate new keys instead of the old certificates for push notifications. They will never expire so there is no need to do that. If you still want to use old certificates, then you should setup some automated build process via AppCenter or something similar just to save your time.